# Computed values in knockout koGrid

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I need to use a grid in which one column has a computed value based on values from other columns in the grid ...

As a sample requirement I have one column which shows the age this is a editable column ... if the age is changed the next column should compute the value of 100 - the updated age ...

I have created a jsfiddle to demo my requirement here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sudarshan89/HtLk5/5/)

```
{field: 'computedAge', displayName: '100 -Age',cellTemplate:self.calculatedCellTemplate}
```

is the computed column that i wish to populate when the age column is updated

Can anyone suggest how i could achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by only two steps:

(1) Create instantiation function for every item in your datalist with `computedAge` computed property within it.

```
function Item(data) {
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    this.age = ko.observable(data.age);
    this.computedAge = ko.computed(function(){
        return 100 - this.age();
    }, this);
}
```

(2) Map source array to create instances instead of simple `observableArray` creation.

```
self.browsers = ko.observableArray(
    ko.utils.arrayMap(
        datastore.initialData,
        function(data){ return new Item(data); }
    )
);
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/xp6xa/

**Update:**
To get self-updating cell do not forget to define your `self.calculatedCellTemplate` like this:

```
    self.calculatedCellTemplate = '<span data-bind="text: $parent.entity.computedAge"></span>';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xp6xa/3/

Comment: Good Work .. Its the only option

Comment: Yes exaclty I just figured this out too :) and have a posted a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/sudarshan89/HtLk5/14/