# Knockout - Total column values in ForEach loop

Tags: knockout.js, breeze, durandal

Extremely new to Knockout (and Durandal/Breeze). . .

I am using Knockout's ForEach to display several columns of forecasted and actual hours for every employee on a project.  What I would like to do is next compute the difference in forecasted and actual hours for each column (hourDiff); I would also like to do formatting for each employee's first and last name.  The data comes in from the server and I am worried that I may have painted myself into a corner in trying to get everything to work correctly up to this point.  The hours are actually nested within each employee object.

```
[n, n]
 0: n
 1: n
   employee: function dependentObservable() {
  __ko_proto__: function (evaluatorFunctionOrOptions, evaluatorFunctionTarget, options) {
  _latestValue: n
  actualHours: Object[0]
 firstName: function dependentObservable() {
 forecastedHours: Object[0]
 lastName: function dependentObservable() {
```

I tried using Knockout's Cart example and it was a bit different than my setup and I couldn't get it to work properly.   I also tried using Knockout's arrayMap, but no luck; it seems the data from the server is not evaluated (I used the example found here: [Computed values in knockout koGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564764/computed-values-in-knockout-kogrid).  My code was just to see if I could pass anything through.):

```
function Item(data) {
        system.log('Within Item');
        this.employee = ko.observable(data.employee);

    }

    var mappedData = ko.observableArray(
     ko.utils.arrayMap(staffingResources, function (data) {
         system.log('Within mappedData');
         return new Item(data);
     }
)
);
```

Here is the viewmodel:

```
define(['durandal/system', 'durandal/app', 'durandal/activator', 'plugins/router', 'jquery', 'knockout', 'services/projectdetailmanager'],
function (system, app, activator, router, $, ko, pdm) {


    var taskID;
    var laborCategories = ko.observableArray();
    var staffingResources = ko.observableArray();
    var staffingHours = ko.observableArray();


    activate = function (context) {
        pdm.clearManager();
        taskID = context.task
        system.log("taskID = " + context.task);
        staffingHours([]);
        staffingResources.removeAll();
        staffingResources([]);
        getStaffingHours(taskID);
        getLaborCategories();
        getStaffingResources(taskID);

    }
    function getStaffingHours(taskID) {
        return pdm.getStaffingHours(taskID)
               .then(function (data) {
                   staffingHours(data);
               });
    };
    function getStaffingResources(taskID) {
        return pdm.getProjectEmployeesByTask(taskID)
               .then(function (data) {
                   staffingResources(data);
               });
    };

    function getLaborCategories() {
        return pdm.getAllLcats()
               .then(function (data) {
                   laborCategories(data);
               });
    };


    hourDiff = ko.computed(function () {
        return 0;

    });


    function save() {
        pdm.saveChanges();
    };


    return {
        activate: activate,
        staffingResources: staffingResources,
        forecastedHours: forecastedHours,
        actualHours: actualHours,
        laborCategories: laborCategories,
        save: save,
        hourDiff: hourDiff,
        addResource: addResource

    };


});
```

And here is the html (right now 'hourDiff' just goes to a regular function for placeholder purposes):

```
<table width="100%" border="0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-weight: bold;">Name</td>
        <td style="font-weight: bold;">Labor Category</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind='foreach: staffingResources'>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;"><span data-bind="text: employee().lastName()" />, <span data-bind="    text: employee().firstName()" /></td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 20%">
            <select data-bind="options: $root.laborCategories, optionsText: 'name', value: laborCategory, event: { change: $root.save }" /></td>



        <!--Next ForEach Here-->



            <!-- Test -->
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>

                        <table border="1">

                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight: bold">Month</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight: bold; width: 20%">Projected: </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight: bold; width: 20%">Actual: </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight: bold">Difference: </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>


                     <!-- ko foreach: $data.employee().hours() -->
                    <td>

                        <table>

                            <tr>
                                <td>Month</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" data-bind="value: forecastedHours, event: { change: $root.save }, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" style="width: 50px;" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" data-bind="value: actualHours, event: { change: $root.save }, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" style="width: 50px;" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span data-bind="text: $root.hourDiff()" /></td>

                            </tr>


                        </table>


                    </td>
                     <!-- /ko -->
                </tr>

            </table>
            <!-- Test -->

     </tr>
                  </tbody>  
            </table>
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I created a fiddle here for ease in viewing: http://jsfiddle.net/JfKkm/

Answer (score 1):

I hope you won't hold it against me, Jimbo, but it feels like you have a mess here. There are a ton of unrelated and inaccessible utilities at play in your script. Don't get me wrong, I think it's cool that you're using AMD but it's only serving to make your question that much more difficult to answer.

I'd like to suggest you simplify your example so that you can get a better understanding of the Knockout's core concepts and we can get a better understanding of your problem. I'm not grasping a cohesive view model in your script. Knockout is based on the MVVM pattern which lends itself well to modeling. The following pseudo code exemplifies the techniques I use for defining my view models. I've also included some examples using computed properties.

```
(function () {
var vm = {
    laborCategories: ko.observableArray([]),
    staffingResources: ko.observableArray([]),
    staffingHours: ko.observableArray([]),
}

// init
var employees = ko.utils.arrayMap(getEmployees(), function(emp) {
    return new Employee(emp); 
});
vm.staffingResources(employees);

// private models
function Employee(data) {
    var model = {
        firstName: ko.observable(data.firstName),
        lastName: ko.observalbe(data.lastName),
        actualHours: ko.observable(data.actualHours),
        forecastedHours: ko.observable(data.forecastedHours),
    }

    model.hourDiff = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.actualHours - this.forecastedHours;
    }, model);
    model.nameFormatted = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.lastName() + ', ' + this.firstName();
    }, model);    
}

ko.applyBindings(model);

// private functions
function getStaffingHours(taskID) {        
}
function getStaffingResources(taskID) {
}
function getLaborCategories() {
}
function save() {
}
})();
```

I hope this helps but forgive me if I've completely missed the mark.

Comment: Hey, Vinney!  Thanks for your answer -- not holding anything against you at all.  I guess I should have mentioned that my code combines Durandal and Breeze as well as Knockout.  Knowing this to be Knockout functionality, I assigned it with a Knockout tag.  Anyway, your code gives me some insights into how to make this work.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Glad I could provide some value! If you'd like more help as you refine your models, please update your question and ping me. Best of luck :)  --- btw, a +1 (upvote) would be appreciated--if you deem my answer worthy, that is. Thanks!

Comment: You got it!  Plus one added. . .